# Function is not going inside else block but returning to if block in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code, my function is not going else block. Also, the readonly class is not getting added or removed on edit click.("readonly not working") When I click on edit the field is enabling but readonly class is not getting added and when I again click on edit the field is not disabling also readonly class is not removing from the field.  what is the reason? Please help me with this. In this code, I want to enable /disable the field on edit click. Here also, I have done that, on edit click the "edit" text gets changes to "cancel" and when I click on cancel the text gets changes to "edit".

my Code  :

```js
function myFunc(a, b){
  // a check
  $(a).click(function(){
    console.log("enable and disabled check");

    if ($(this).parents('.info-details').find(b).hasClass('readonly')){
      // disable field
      console.log("disabled field");
      $(this).parents('.info-details').find(b).removeClass('readonly');
      $(b).prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      //enable field
      console.log("enabled field");

      $(this).parents('.info-details').find(b).addClass('readonly');
      $(b).prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
}

$("#demo").html(myFunc('#edit_data_email','#change_email'));
$("#demo").html(myFunc('#edit_data_number','#change_mobile_number'));
```

What is the main reason for a function to not go inside else block? Also, How readonly class works?

Comment: please also supply your html

Comment: Firstly, your function `myFunc` returns `undefined` which you use to set `#demo` html. I'm really not sure what you are trying to do here?!

Comment: None of this code makes much sense. Explain what this code is supposed to be doing...in words

Comment: <form class="form-acc-details heighlight-email" role="form" class="recorrect_email">
 <div class="info-email" id="demo">
    <div class="info">
     <button type="button" class="edit-data" id='edit_data_email'>Edit</button></div>
 <div class="fill-information">
   <div class="fill-form-info form-group col-md-4">
    <input type="email" class="my-info form-control" value="Abcd@gmail.com" id="change_email" disabled required/>
     </div> <button type="submit" class="btn-submit btn btn-primary" id="save-email">Save</button>
   </div>
  </div> </form>

Comment: Please don't dump raw code in comment blocks. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47558678/edit) the question with properly formatted code and any clarifiction updates

Answer (score 1):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/432/)**.

First of all you don't have to attach an event inside a function, it will be better if you give your edit elements a common class then attach the click event to them using this class, like :

```
<div class="info-details">
  <input id="change_email" />
  <button class="edit_data">Edit</button>
</div>

<div class="info-details">
  <input id="change_mobile_number" />
  <button class="edit_data">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Code:

```js
$('.edit_data').click(function() {
  console.log("enable and disabled check");
  var input = $(this).parents('.info-details').find('input');

  if (input.hasClass('readonly')) {
    console.log("disabled field");

    input.removeClass('readonly');
    input.prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    console.log("enabled field");

    input.addClass('readonly');
    input.prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info-details">
  <input id="change_email" class='readonly' />
  <button class="edit_data">Edit</button>
</div>

<div class="info-details">
  <input id="change_mobile_number" class='readonly' />
  <button class="edit_data">Edit</button>
</div>
```